# How do I play a level online with other players in LittleBigPlanet?

Tags: little-big-planet

I have been trying and trying and trying to play a level online with other players in *LittleBigPlanet* (there are some challenges and puzzles that require 3 and 4 players to solve).   I login and when I go to choose levels I see the number of players playing each level, but there isn't an option to play a level online or to join players in progress.  When I start to play the level, I'm all alone.

How do I play online with someone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just go into the level you want to play and than wait for other to join (You have to stay near the entrance of the level though. If you go past the sackbody sign the game will close it.
Be patient and someone will pop-out. (Hopefully a skilled player)
Or you can send invitation to your friends while waiting for them in the level. (Send them a message with the name of the level).
Have fun :)

Comment: No other players can join once someone passes the "Close-Level Post" (the one with the sign that has a Sackboy face on it that, when crossed, spins and turns into a crossed-out Sackboy face).

Answer (score 0):

Go to where it says (MORE) and go to friends, then find the ONLINE section and press any online friend you want.