# Little Big Planet - how do I get people to join me to solve puzzles?

Tags: ps3, little-big-planet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I play a level online with other players in LittleBigPlanet?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5898/how-do-i-play-a-level-online-with-other-players-in-littlebigplanet)

When I'm navigating the planets, I see an indicator that shows how many people are on that board. How do I get one of them to join me? Is there a lobby of some sort that I'm missing?